# Convert columns to rows with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have an output file in the following format. How can I convert this into csv with first column as header row and second column as data row?

Input:

```
"Node name","SLAVE_DB"
"Node ID","2"
"PostgreSQL version","10.17"
"Total data size","1 GB"
"Conninfo","host=192.168.0.1 port=5432 user=user dbname=postgres"
"Role","standby"
"WAL archiving","disabled (on standbys "archive_mode" must be set to "always" to be effective)"
```

Desired Output:

```
"Node name","Node ID","PostgreSQL version","Total data size","Conninfo","Role","WAL archiving"
"SLAVE_DB","2","10.17","1 GB","host=192.168.0.1 port=5432 user=user dbname=postgres","standby","disabled (on standbys ""archive_mode"" must be set to ""always"" to be effective)"
```

[Edit]
I read through similar questions and I tried `awk -F "," '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) printf $i ", " }'`
but it does not produce the desired output. I also want to preserve the quoted fields with in the data.

Comment: @Fravadona: Yes, output will always be in this format

Comment: The quoted input strings will not contain commas or newlines, but will contain unescaped quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that there's never quotes in your first field (the tag/name/header), then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    tags[NR] = $1
    vals[NR] = $2
}
END {
    for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NR; colNr++ ) {
        tag = tags[colNr]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (colNr<NR ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NR; colNr++ ) {
        val = vals[colNr]
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",val)
        gsub(/"/,"\"\"",val)
        printf "\"%s\"%s", val, (colNr<NR ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
"Node name","Node ID","PostgreSQL version","Total data size","Conninfo","Role","WAL archiving"
"SLAVE_DB","2","10.17","1 GB","host=192.168.0.1 port=5432 user=user dbname=postgres","standby","disabled (on standbys ""archive_mode"" must be set to ""always"" to be effective)"
```

If you need more than that then see [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Comment: Your assumptions is correct that it is always an unescaped quote. I made a mistake in the input. Thanks a lot for the solution!